# how can i change element.style in vue.js?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuetify.js

i am learning vue/vuetify/node on video guides, 
but there guy using old version of this and i have some trouble with element.style [image]

i want to change position of labels, move the email address and password to the left side of the input window. in my code it looks like that:

```
          <v-text-field
          dense
          label="Email"
          v-model="email" 
          color="#00BCD4"
           />
```

I made a demo for clarity how it works for me https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-fast-qfhdz?file=/src/main.js

Comment: "_move the email address and password to the right side_" your labels seems to be already on the right side!?

Comment: oh sorry, i need move to the left side

Comment: What is the value of `this.$vuetify.rtl`?

Comment: if I understand correctly how to watch it, then this is undefined, i have tried to switch true or ltr to true, nothing happened

Comment: Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue) to show the issue happening.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-fast-qfhdz?file=/src/main.js

Answer (score 0):

Vuetify supports RTL (right-to-left) text layouts (like for Arabic or Hebrew). This is usually set at the application level.

If you created your app using the Vuetify "Quick Start" (i.e. `vue create myapp` followed by `vue add vuetify`), then you should have a file at `src/plugins/vuetify.js` in which you'll see something like:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

const options = {
  rtl: true,
  // ... possibly other options ...
}

export const new Vuetify(options)
```

Or if you're loading Vue and Vuetify into a browser, wherever you created your Vuetify object, you likely passed it an `rtl` property like:

```js
const vuetify = new Vuetify({
  rtl: true,
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify,
})
```

This should set ALL of the text on your site to be RTL.

Alternatively, the text alignment within a component can be set with [one of the text alignment utility classes](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/text/#rtl-alignment), **BUT these classes have NO effect on `v-text-field` instances**:

```html
<!-- THESE CLASSES HAVE NO EFFECT -->
<v-text-field
  v-model="name"
  class="text-right"
/>
OR
<v-text-field
  v-model="name"
  class="text-end"
/>
```

Based on this, I think you added the `rtl` property in your Vuetify configuration somewhere, or possibly changed it later using `this.$vuetify.rtl = true` (as @Ohgodwhy indicated in a comment)

Comment: i did not add rtl anywhere, i have tried class text-right , it did not work for me